# double_baking_evidence and double_endorsement_evidence

Tags: node

I understand the double_baking_evidence and double_endorsement_evidence.I need some help to understand

1. the baker that performed the double_* and the baker that provided the evidence , does the reward(the baker providing evidence) and loss(loss of rewards + deposits for the baker that baked the block) happen at the same time or they are again freezed.

2.Can anybody help me understand the balance_update section.

3. This example is for double_baking_evidence

   "metadata": {

"balance_updates": [

{
"kind": "freezer",
                                    "category": "deposits",
                                    "delegate": "tz1PeZx7FXy7QRuMREGXGxeipb24RsMMzUNe",
                                    "cycle": 135,
                                    "change": "-64000000"
                                },

```
                            {
                                "kind": "freezer",
                                "category": "rewards",
                                "delegate": "tz1PeZx7FXy7QRuMREGXGxeipb24RsMMzUNe",
                                "cycle": 135,
                                "change": "-2000000"
                            },
                            {
                                "kind": "freezer",
                                "category": "rewards",
                                "delegate": "tz1Yju7jmmsaUiG9qQLoYv35v5pHgnWoLWbt",
                                "cycle": 135,
                                "change": "32000000"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I case of double_baking, half of the deposits and fees of the offender is burnt and the other half is given to the baker that includes the double_baking operation as reward *for this cycle*. The rewards of the offender are just burnt.

In your example tz1PeZ...UNe lost all its 64 xtz of deposits, 32 of which were given to tz1Yju...Wbt which I imagine is the baker for that level. The remaining 2 xtz of rewards of tz1PeZ...UNe are just burnt. It looks like tz1PeZ...UNe didn't have any fees, which is odd.

Next time it would be useful to have the exact command that you run, or at least the level.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , could you help me for point 1 .